# Order Associative Array by Specific Key Values

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach, associative-array

I have the following array:

```
   $data=array(
   'Points'=>$points,'Name'=>$row['Name'], 'Phone'=>$row['phone']
    );
```

This resides in a for each loop in my Codeigniter controller index function:

```
public function index(){

    $query=$this->My_model->get_data();
    foreach ($query as $row)
    {
           $data=array(
           'Points'=>$points,'Name'=>$row['Name'], 'Phone'=>$row['phone']
            );

    }
}
```

Currently if I print_r on $data it would produce:

```
Array ( [Points] => 500 [Name] => Dave Laus ) 
Array ( [Points] => 1200 [Name] => John Smith ) 
Array ( [Points] => 700 [Name] => Jason Smithsonian )
```

However I would like to sort/order this so that the user with the highest points showing first like this:

```
Array ( [Points] => 1200 [Name] => John Smith ) 
Array ( [Points] => 700 [Name] => Jason Smithsonian ) 
Array ( [Points] => 500 [Name] => Dave Laus )
```

I want to sort the array by the "Points" key, so that the user with the highest points appear first. I want to re order the array to show from highest to lowest points.

I have tried usort and arsort and ksort. I haven't gotten it to work.

How do I do this?

I tried this in my controller, but it's doesn't work, errors instead:

```
public function index(){

    $query=$this->My_model->get_data();
    foreach ($query as $row)
    {
           $data=array(
           array('Points'=>$points,'Name'=>$row['Name'], 'Phone'=>$row['phone']),
            );

           function cmp ($a, $b) {
        return $a['Points'] < $b['Points'] ? 1 : -1;
        }

        usort($data, "cmp");

            print_r($data);


                //I also tried usort($leaders, array('home', 'cmp')); whcih gave no errors, but was the same result as before, not ordered


        }
    }
```

Comment: it shoud be $data[]= array... right ? otherwise you're rewriting the same array every time

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you provided better data examples. You say you want to sort by `Points` key but you are showing us a one-dimensional array - with only one `Points` key. Show us an example of the data before sorting, and what you want it to look like after.

Comment: @MarkM Please see edits

Comment: Should also show the code of the usort/ksort that you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function cmp ($a, $b) {
    return $a['Points'] < $b['Points'] ? 1 : -1;
}

usort($data, "cmp");
```

[**See Demo**](http://codepad.org/cAeFe0Ij)

Comment: Tried this, see code above in the OP, but I get errors. Thought the CodeIgniter tag would be fine, should have also stated it in the OP.

Comment: I also tried using usort($leaders, array('home', 'cmp'));, no errors, but it produced the same unordered array.

Comment: @Tester `$cmp=$this->cmp($a,$b)` is not gonna work. Put the `cmp` function directly in the `index` function and call it the way it is in my answer. Also, not sure where `$leaders` comes from... thought it was `$data`...

Comment: I tried it that way (see the code edits above), it prints only the first item in the array "Array ( [0] => Array ( [Points] => 500 [Name] => Lerielle Cole ) ) ", and gives an error under the printed "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare cmp() (previously declared in.....", in my controller file where I put the code.

Comment: Ok, I actually fixed it, was a minor error, now when I print or echo, I can see the list now ordered by points. However, the fatal error I described in the above comment still remains, so the page can't display results through the view, only when I print or echo throught he controller. ANy ideas on how to get rid of the fatal error? @Mark M

Comment: Sorted it out, needed to put the cmp function and sort outside of the loop to fix the fatal error. Thanks for the help with this

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the usort [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). You have to create a callback function that will compare 2 elements of the array. You have examples of such callback functions used by sorting procedures in the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Following function will allow you to sort the given array using specific field along with direction (asc or desc).
It accepts parameters as

```
// $field = field / key for sorting
// $array = array to sort
// $direction = ascending or descending sort direction (default is ascending)


function sortBy($field, &$array, $direction = 'asc')
{
    usort($array, create_function(  '$a, $b', '
                                     $a = $a["' . $field . '"];
                                     $b = $b["' . $field . '"];
                                     if ($a == $b) {
                                         return 0;
                                     }

                                     return ($a ' . ($direction == 'desc' ? '>' : '<') .' $b) ? -1 : 1;'));

    return true;
}
```

Now use following code to actually sort the array

```
sortBy('Points', $data, 'desc'); // sorts in descending order for value of key Points
sortBy('Name', $data, 'asc'); // sorts in ascending order for value of key Name
```

I suggest you take a look at following link 
http://phpave.com/sorting-associative-array-specific-key/